# How to get json data from model in angular

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular12

Tried to get JSON data from the model but it is not working. Only it is working when i use    this.products.allproduct['product1'];. But in my application, I am passing the object name. So, depends on passing object name data will appear.

If i use this.products.allproduct[prd]; not working. How to resolve this issue.

app.component.html:

```
<button (click)="getData('product1')">Product 1</button>
<button (click)="getData('product2')">Product 2</button>
<button (click)="getData('product3')">Product 3</button>

<div>
  {{showData}}
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
getData(prd: string|number) {
    this.showData = this.products.allproduct[prd]; 
  }
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kng5nw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Do you want to show the `showData` as json printed on the view? if so you could just add JsonPipe eg `{{ showData | json }}` . Read more here https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

Answer (score 0):

Its array of objects and showing correctly.
Use ngFor for loop on the inner array.

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of showData;let i = index;">
  {{row.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: this.showData = this.products.allproduct[prd];   not working for me.  if i use this this.showData = this.products.allproduct['product1'];  only working.So why it is not working  this.products.allproduct[prd];

Comment: I am getting this error:Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type